# Verify and cut a string using regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I have the following string:

```
{'output',{'variable','VGRG_Pos_Var1/Parameters/D_foo'},'date',734704.60904050921}
```

I would like to verify the format of the string that the word 'variable' is the second word and i would like to retrive the string after the last '/' in the 3rd string (In this example 'D_foo').

how could i verify this and retrive the sting i search?

I tried the following:

```
regexp(str,'{''\w+'',{''variable'',''([(a-z)|(A-Z)|/|_])+')
```

without success

**REMARK**

The string to analysis is not splited after the komma, it is only due to length of the string.

**EDIT**

my string is:

```
'{''output'',{''variable'',''VGRG_Pos_Var1/Parameters/D_foo''},''date'',734704.60904050921}';
```

and not a cell, which could be understood. I added the sybol ' at the start and end of the string to symbolizied that it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that you mention using regexp in the question, but I'm not sure if this is a requirement? If other solutions are acceptable you could try this:

```
str='{''output'',{''variable'',''VGRG_Pos_Var1/Parameters/D_foo''},''date'',734704.60904050921}';
parts1=textscan( str, '%s','delimiter',{',','{','}'},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
parts2=textscan( parts1{1}{3}, '%s','delimiter',{'/',''''},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);

string=parts2{1}{end}
match=strcmp(parts1{1}{2},'variable')
```

Comment: no i doesn't need to be done with regexp. I hope to be able to sove it with two lines of code instead of 4. (Verifing and split). Nether the less, your solution solve my problem and for that i am thankful.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, you can write this:

```
str = {'output',{'variable','VGRG_Pos_Var1/Parameters/D_foo'},'date',734704.60904050921};
temp = str(2); %this holds the cell containing the two strings
if cmpstr(temp{1}(1), 'variable') 
   %do stuff
end
```

For the second part you can do this:

```
str = {'output',{'variable','VGRG_Pos_Var1/Parameters/D_foo'},'date',734704.60904050921};
temp = str(2); %like before, this contains the cell
temp = temp{1}(2); %this picks out the second string in the cell
temp = char(temp); %turns the item from a cell to a string
res = strsplit(temp, '/'); %splits the string where '/' are found, res is an array of strings
string = res(3); %assuming there will always be just 2 '/'s.
```